# How do I strip pass phrase from a private key with 3072 bits - Got Error need fix

Tags: encryption, openssl

I created  a CSR SSL Certificate request and successfully generated the cert files from the CA , however when I went to strip the passphrase which I have on file I got an error most likely because I created the private key with 3072 bits and not the default amount of bits.  Now I have a problem it seems trying to strip the passphrase.

Here is what I did:

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.key 3072`

I will skip the steps that follow because all I need do is strip the key above mykey.key of the pass code.

`openssl rsa -in mykey.key -out nopc_mykey.key`

I should be able to do this and all should work fine but the 3072 bits seem to cause a problem namely:

> unable to load Private Key
>   140538251888456:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:535:
>   140538251888456:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:pem_lib.c:476:

Any ideas how I can fix this and strip the passcode for SSL? Perhaps some way to provide the number of bits used to create the key in the first place?

Comment: What openssl version are you using? I've tried with both openssl 1.0.1 and openssl 0.9.8d and in both the versions, I have no problem getting rid of the password. openssl rsa -in mykey.key -out nopc_mykey.key
Enter pass phrase for mykey.key:
writing RSA key

Answer (score 1):

Please be informed that key size must be 2048 bit. All SSL Certificates in use must be 2048 bit in accordance with CA/B Forum guidelines.

See: https://www.globalsign.com/ssl-information-center/1024-bit-public-and-private-keys.html

You may refer to this link on how to Generate a CSR in OpenSSL:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1221018-generate-csr---apache-openssl